# Inserir caminho de imagem na BD e ficheiro no servidor

Tags: php, html

Eu tinha um formulario de inserçao para adicionar alguns campos. Mas tambem queria inserir uma imagem para uma pasta no servidor e o caminho da imagem para uma tabela na base de dados mas nao tou a conseguir.

```
<form action="enviar_registo_produto.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" >

    <div class="status alert alert-success" style="display: none"></div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Nome</label>
        <input name="nome" class="form-control" placeholder="(Nome do Produto)">
    </div>

    <input name="id_produto" type="hidden" class="form-control">

    <div  class="form-group">
        <label>Preço</label>
        <input name="preco" class="form-control" placeholder="(Preco Do Produto)">
    </div>

    <div  class="form-group">
        <label>Descrição</label>
        <textarea name="descricao" class="form-control" placeholder="(Descrição do Produto)" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div  class="form-group">
        <label>Foto do Produto</label>
        <input name="foto" type="file" size="100">
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_SIZE_FILE" value="300000">
    </div>

    <div  class="form-group">
        <label>id_categoria</label>
        <select name="id_categoria" class="form-control">
            <option value="1">1 - Pratos Do Dia</option>
            <option value="2">2 - Petiscos</option>
            <option value="3">3 - Bebidas</option>
            <option value="4">4 - Sobremesas</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-outline btn-primary btn-sm">Enviar</button>
    <input type="reset" class="btn btn-outline btn-warning btn-sm" name="BTApaga" value="Apagar">

    <br/>
    <br/>  
</form>
```

E no php tenho este codigo que esta constantemente a dar-me o erro "Ocorreu um erro durante o upload"

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

$nome=($_POST["nome"]);
$preco=($_POST["preco"]);
$descricao=($_POST["descricao"]);
$id_categoria=($_POST["id_categoria"]);

$tamanho_maximo = $_POST["MAX_SIZE_FILE"];
$tipos_imagem = array("image/gif", "image/jpeg", "image/x-png", "image/bmp");
$ficheiro = $_FILES['foto'];

include ("ligaBD.php");

$existe="Select * from Produtos where nome='$nome'";

$faz_existe= mysqli_query($ligaBD, $existe);

$jaexiste= mysqli_num_rows($faz_existe);

if($jaexiste==0){
    if ($ficheiro['error'] != 0) {
        echo '<p>Erro no upload do ficheiro!<br>';
        switch ($ficheiro['error']) {
            case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
                echo 'O ficheiro excede o tamanho máximo permitido!';
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
                echo 'O ficheiro enviado é muito grande!';
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL:
                echo 'O processo de upload não foi concluído!';
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
                echo 'Não foi indicado nenhum ficheiro para upload!';
                break;
        }
        echo '</p>';
        exit;
    }

    if ($ficheiro['size']==0 OR $ficheiro['tmp_name']==NULL) {
        echo "<script>alert('Nenhum ficheiro enviado');window.location ='insert_produtos.php';</script>";
        exit;
    }

    if ($ficheiro['size']>$tamanho_maximo) {
        echo '<p>O ficheiro enviado é muito grande (Tamanho máximo = ' . $tamanho_maximo . ')</p>';
        exit;
    }

    $destino = '../../imagens_produtos/';
    $destino .= $ficheiro['name'];

    if (!move_uploaded_file($ficheiro['tmp_name'],$destino)) {
        echo "<script>alert('Ocorreu um erro durante o Upload!');window.location ='insert_produtos.php';</script>";
    } else {
        $insere_produto= "INSERT INTO Produtos( nome, preco, descricao, foto, id_categoria) VALUES ('".$nome."','".$preco."','".$descricao."','".$ficheiro['name']."','".$id_categoria."')";

        $faz_insere_produto= mysqli_query($ligaBD, $insere_produto);

        echo"<script>alert('Produto inserido com sucesso!');window.location ='index.php';</script>";
    }

} else {
    echo "<script>alert('O nome do produto ja existe!');window.location ='insert_produtos.php';</script>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Está a dar algum erro específico ou apenas não funciona?

Comment: Aparece-me estes dois erros:

Comment: Warning: move_uploaded_file(../../imagens_produtos/13D910D5.PNG): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /homes/i15630/public_html/PAP_TASQUINHA/AdminPanel/enviar_registo_produto.php on line 61

Comment: Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phprxqr03' to '../../imagens_produtos/13D910D5.PNG' in /homes/i15630/public_html/PAP_TASQUINHA/AdminPanel/enviar_registo_produto.php on line 61 @Leite

Comment: O destino presumo que seja `~/i5630/public_html/PAP_TASQUINHA/imagens_produtos`, essa pasta existe e tem as permissões correctas?

Comment: Sim existe, ja verifiquei as permissões e tem todas

Comment: Sugiro que passe o destino completo, ao invés de só ../../imagens_produtos/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema parece estar no caminho para a pasta de destino da imagem, o caminho relativo não estará correcto por o php estar a correr noutra pasta que não a que tem o ficheiro que faz upload, isto deve ser alguma configuração especifica do ambiente em que o php está a correr.

Sugeria que definisses uma variável que seja a pasta onde o teu ficheiro que faz upload está e depois usasses isso como a "raiz" para o teu caminho

```
// CWD - current working dir, mas podes dar o nome que quiseres claro
define('CWD', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));

// altera o teu $destino para fazer uso dessa variável
$destino = CWD.'../../imagens_produtos/';
$destino .= $ficheiro['name'];
```

Outra opção será a variável `$destino` ser um caminho absoluto invés de ser relativo, o problema desta solução é que se mudares esta aplicação de servidor, quase de certeza deixa de funcionar pois os caminhos serão diferentes.

```
$destino = '/homes/i15630/public_html/PAP_TASQUINHA/imagens_produtos/';
$destino .= $ficheiro['name'];
```

Comment: Funcionou da primeira opção @leite

Comment: Boa! Aceita a resposta, pode ser útil para alguém que tenha um problema parecido de futuro :)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda e cumprimentos!

Comment: Boa sorte pra PAP (Fiz a minha a 15 anos já...)! Espero que te corra bem depois a apresentação, pessoalmente, parece-me que te estás a safar bem :)

Comment: Obrigado :) mas eu ja fiz a minha o ano passado, fiz um site de venda de produtos informáticos. Esta é para uma colega que está nessa fase e estou a tentar da uma mãozinha